# How do you debug linking errors in React Native iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

For instance RCTImageLoader being undefined:

[image]

It's part of the Image library in RN:

[image]

And I have this in my `Podfile`:

have this line in my Podfile: `pod 'React', :subspecs => ['Core', 'RCTImage', 'RCTNetwork', 'RCTLinkingIOS', 'RCTText', 'RCTWebSocket'], :path => '../node_modules/react-native'`

And here are my libraries:
[image]

I have tried:

- Project -> Clean
- running `pod install` again
- deleting `Podfile.lock` && `pod install`
- fresh git clone, `npm install && cd ios && pod install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try manually adding header files, for instance `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTImageLoader.h`.

However in my case, that didn't help. The solution was to open `MyProject.xcworkspace` instead of `MyProject.xcproject`

Answer (score 0):

make sure the .m file has been compile (->Build Phases -> Compile Sources)